# XIB - UIView or UIControllerView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, xib

I am new to iOS development. I am trying to implement a XIB in my app. I want to add this XIB as part of a view, and I want to be able to get/catch the clicks/taps happening on this XIB's subviews (a button, image, etc).

At first, I set the XIB's File Owner class to a UIView subclass, but now I see no way to handle the clicks/taps from this subclass into my ViewController.

Should I (and am I allowed to) set the File Owner class to my ViewController class instead? Is that allowed? How should we handle these taps/clicks made in XIBs?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not set the FileOwner to the ViewController. You should add a gesture recognizer to the ViewController, and add that gestureRecognizer to the view.

I don't know in Swift, but in objective c you would do something like:

`UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarger:customView action:@selector(mySelector)];`

Answer (score 0):

File's Owner is a proxy or stand-in for an actual object that will be identified when the nib is loaded. *[ed. I should note "nib" is the old school term for interface files.  xib is the new-fangled name.  Actually xib files compile down to nib files when your project is built.  Forgive me if I'm a bit old school and use nib/xib interchangeably]* You could choose to use your view controller as the "File's Owner" in your interface file.  Using it might look something like this:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet loadedView : UIView!

    func loadMyInterface() {
        // load the nib with myself as the "Files Owner".  If the nib file is set up properly
        // shoudl set the "loadedView" outlet on this object
        Bundle.mainBundle.loadNibNamed("MyLoadedView", owner: self, options: nil)

    }
}
```

In this code snippet, I have the `loadedView` outlet.  When my view controller is created this will be `nil`.  Then at some point in the execution of my program I call `loadMyInterface`.  That routine will ask the main bundle to load the interface file "MyLoadedView".  Note that it is at this point that I tell the system what object "File's Owner" represents.  Because I have identified my view controller as the `owner` then any outlets in the interface file that are identified for the File's owner will be wired to that view controller.

Additionally, you could define Actions on your view controller class and wire those up to the "File's Owner" in interface builder and when the lib is loaded they will be directed to the view controller.

Note, however that this is simply because I identified my view controller as the `owner` when the nib was loaded.  I could just have easily set up any other object as the File's Owner and directed that outlets and actions for the owner should go there.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple you create a custom class for the Xib just like you do with the viewController with outlets for buttons and labels, IBAction and more. Then you create an protocol that it follows and set the delegate to that protocol from your target MainView and ViewController where you want display the Xib. when clicking the button in Xib, it will refer to the protocol and call a function in the viewController.

CustomView:

```
protocol customViewDelegate: class {
func buttonClicked()
}

class CustomView: UIView {
weak var delegate: customViewDelegate?

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     delegate?.buttonClicked()
}
}
```

And the ViewController:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, customViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: CustomView!

var customView: CustomView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
customView = CustomView.loadFromNib()
customView.delegate = self
}
func buttonClicked() {
     //Do what you wanted to do when the button inside the Xib was clicked.
}
}
```